# read yml file properties using java

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I am trying to read YML file using java but not able to do. Object is null. I have refereed many examples but no luck . Little help will be appreciated.

ApplicationProperties contain pojo for yml file. My intention is to read values only.

```
InputStream inputStream = LoadExternalConfiguration.class.getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("application.yml");
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(ApplicationProperties.class));
HashMap yamlMap = yaml.load(inputStream);
System.out.println(yamlMap);
for (Object o : yamlMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(o);
}

inputStream.close();
```

application.yml

```
dmsMapping:
  input_layer_name : "sign-values"
  output_Layer_volatile : "dms-range-v1"
  output_layer_IML : "dms-ts-mapped-data-iml"
```

Comment: Are you sure that in your YAML there should be equals signs between keys and values? Because in YAML it should be colons. I will not form this as an answer because I'm not sure if you just copy-pasted wrong or this is the actual problem.

Comment: Its my bad. Basically I tried another by using properties file and reading all config from there but facing issue with .yml . I have updated yml file